# Why is my iOS app forcing a Settings Bundle

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I can not figure out why when I debug my app it always has a Settings Bundle. The only option in the settings page is "Use Cellular Data." It has the Settings Bundle on my iPhone 6 Plus, but not on my 4S. I have deleted my app, cleaned my project, and deleted the derived data in Organizer. I have never had a Settings.bundle in my project before. I've tested all my libraries in another app, it does not force a setting bundle. Both iPhones are running iOS 8.2. Is there anything I'm missing? Is there any secret Xcode build setting or plist setting that's forcing this Settings Bundle?

Comment: Every app under iOS 8 gets a Settings page - even without a Settings bundle - it's a feature. You must have iOS 7 or earlier on your 4S.

Comment: @rmaddy No, this is not true, at least not without some other context. My 4S is certainly iOS 8 and I have plenty of apps on both phones that do not have a settings page.

Comment: Yes, it is true. iOS 8 now shows a Settings page for all apps. If the app does not have a settings bundle then the only thing shown on the settings page is the option to allow cellular data or not. If I remember correctly, this settings page doesn't show up until the first time you use the app while you only have a cellular connection (no WiFi). So perhaps you haven't used your app on the 4S yet while only having a cellular connection.

Comment: One other thing I forgot. The Settings page will also appear if the app uses various privacy settings such as location, camera, etc. Also notifications and background refresh result in the settings page even if there is no settings bundle.

Comment: @rmaddy That's it! Thank you very much. The key is that the settings page will not show until the app uses cellular data, or as you mentioned other services. If you want to put your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 8.0, a settings page is shown for all apps even if the app doesn't have a settings bundle.

The iOS 8 settings page appears without a settings bundle if the app does any of the following:

- Attempts to access data via a cellular network
- Various privacy data

  - Camera
  - Microphone
  - Photo library
  - Contacts
- Location
- Notifications
- Background data fetch

A settings page may not appear for an app if none of these conditions have yet been met.

Comment: My app has a toggle switch for "Cellular Data", but to my knowledge I am never using data or internet. Is there a way to disable all data in my app, and thus not receive this automatic `settings.bundle`?

Comment: @pkamb Are you using a 3rd party library? It make be making network calls you don't know about.

Comment: No, I'm not. Just a standard Single View Xcode Swift app example project. This "automatic settings" feature is very annoying as it makes linking to the main page of Settings.app impossible... the `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` link goes to your app's settings, when/if that settings page is (randomly) created.

Comment: @pkamb That's the point of `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`. It's only purpose is to take the user to your app's Settings page. There is no way to go to any other page in the Settings app.

Comment: Well, it sometimes serves as a convenient shortcut to iOS Settings for manually enabling your App Extensions. Until you install on a device, that is, and the link suddenly starts going to your useless "app settings"!