# Remove App From iPhone Settings

Tags: ios, iphone, bundle

I currently have an iOS application that does not need or have any user settings or system settings in the built in **Settings** app of the device.

I want to know how to programmatically remove the app (or stop having it added when downloaded) from the Settings portion of the iPhone? I have researched plenty of threads/blogs that discuss editing, creating, and managing the Settings.bundle feature offered by Xcode, but none really cover *how* to delete the app completely from being added to the Settings. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **prior to iOS 8**:

You need to delete the Settings.bundle all together. Then clean targets after you delete the Settings.bundle and then delete Root.plist

For more details check out this conversation: [How to Delete settings.bundle](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/19727-how-to-delete-settings-bundle.html)

From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW18):

> A Settings bundle has the name Settings.bundle and resides in the top-level directory of your app’s bundle. This bundle contains one or more Settings page files that describe the individual pages of preferences. It may also include other support files needed to display your preferences, such as images or localized strings.

For **iOS 8 and after** according to [rmaddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197119/why-is-my-ios-app-forcing-a-settings-bundle?answertab=oldest#tab-top) to [Why is my iOS app forcing a Settings Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197119/why-is-my-ios-app-forcing-a-settings-bundle):

> As of iOS 8.0, a settings page is shown for all apps even if the app doesn't have a settings bundle.
>
> The iOS 8 settings page appears without a settings bundle if the app does any of the following:
>
> Attempts to access data via a cellular network
> Various privacy data
> Camera
> Microphone
> Photo library
> Contacts
> Location
> Notifications
> Background data fetch
> A settings page may not appear for an app if none of these conditions have yet been met.

Comment: I had read through that convo before - the only issue is, I am not sure where the Settings.bundle is located in my project, if it exists at all. I never created one manually so I'm not sure how to "delete it" per say. Is there a default set somewhere that automatically places the app in the settings?

Comment: @WillVonUllrich, I made a few more changes that answers your question.

Comment: still cant seem to get it to delete yet, but i'll keep trying

Comment: You cannot in iOS 8 unless you meet the requirements.

Comment: well shoot. that's that lol. thanks!