# How to Handle iOS Settings if App Uses the Network?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, settings

I have an app, in which the user can initiate a short, asynchronous download to access data on the internet, and then the app displays that data. The app is not yet released, but I have tested it on both simulator and several physical devices. On none of them, however, I can locate the app inside the settings menu where I could, for instance, restrict its network access to WiFi only, etc.

I assumed that if my app accesses the internet, it would automatically appear in the settings menu, but apparently it is not so. Am I doing something wrong? What is the process to allow the user to access such basic settings?

I use XCode 10.3, and probram in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is that there's not a settings entry for your app, please keep in mind that sometimes, in order for an app to be registered, you may need to close your app and the settings app and try opening it again.

If the problem is that you don't see the standard settings for location services, cellular data etc, then you may find maddy's answer here to be helpful: [Why is my iOS app forcing a Settings Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197119/why-is-my-ios-app-forcing-a-settings-bundle) might be helpful.

Copying the relevant part from this answer:

> The iOS 8+ settings page appears […] if the app does any of the
>   following:
>
> - Attempts to access data via a cellular network
> - Various privacy data
> - Camera
> - Microphone
> - Photo library
> - Contacts
> - Location
> - Notifications
> - Background data fetch
>
> A settings page may not appear for an app if none of these conditions
>   have yet been met.

Comment: Hmm, this is strange. I do use cellular data (I know because I’ve tested is specifically), and both the app and settings have been restarted several times. Yet, the app does not appear in the settings. I wonder if it is because it hasn’t been released yet...

Comment: I noticed the same behavior (iOS 12.4 - on Simulator). To actually have my unpublished app show in settings, I had to add a settings.bundle to my project. However, even though the switch for location services appeared, once I replied to the first prompt for accessing location services in the app, no cellular data option appeared.

Comment: The app "magically" appeared in the settings for reasons I cannot see. I have not changed anything; it just appeared. I am going to mark your answer as the correct one; although, I still have no idea why and how this whole thing works.